# How to copy folders and files from RDP server to local computer with Powershell

Tags: powershell, rdp

I want to copy some folders from a server (which is not mapped as a network drive, it is only accessible through RDP connection) and to paste it to my local folder.

I found a piece of code like:

```
echo "connecting to server-10-15"
$Server="server-10-15"
$User="Administrator"
$Password="AdminPassword"
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
mstsc /v:$Server
```

But I want to add some code after I log in just to copy some folders to mine local machine, and then to close connection.

Is it possible or I need to do with GUI RDP window to achieve this?

---

**Update**

I am trying  with `Enter-PSSession MyServerName -Credential domain\username`
Then it prompts me for a password, and after I enter my correct password, it throws me an error

```
+ Category Info: InvalidArgument: (MyServerName:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Comment: Have you looked into PS Remoting to solve some of theses issues? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6

Comment: @Mötz I've tried with PSRemoting tooling, but no luck. Please see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

The [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) command has both `ToSession` and `FromSession` parameters which do as what names imply.

To copy a file from a remote session:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server01 -Credential 'Domain\Username'
Copy-Item 'C:\RemoteFolder\RemoteFile.log' -Destination 'D:\MyLocalFolder\' -FromSession $Session
```